# When are multiplication operators on $L^2$ unitarily equivalent?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Consider $L^2[0,1]$.  Are the operations of multiplaction by $x$ and multiplication by $x^2$ unitarily equivalent on this space?

What about the operation of multiplication by $x^2$ on $L^2[-1,1]$ vs multiplication by $x^2$ on $L^2[0,1]$?  Are they unitarily equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

On $L^2[0,1]$,  $Uf(x) = \sqrt{2x} f(x^2)$ is a unitary operator such that
$U \circ M_x = M_{x^2} \circ U$.